# Show the date always without seconds is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a page to edit the administrators of a post. I have some radio buttons in this page, each radio button corresponds to an administrator. When an administratotr is selected the details of that administrator appears on the form fields below the radio buttons.

One form field is a date. Im using cabon to show in this edit post administrators page the date in this format "format('d F Y - H:i')":

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type='text' name="date" value="{{ $admin->date->format('d F Y - H:i') }}"
           class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```

And it works fine. The date appears on this format: "07 February 2018 - 6:30".

But then I have some jQuery that receives an array with the administrators of the post from the controller and populate the details of each administrator in the form when the corresponding radio button is selected.

With this jQuery when this edit administrators page is acessed the date appears on this same format ""07 February 2018 - 6:30". But then if some amdinistrator is selected through the radio button the date field of that administrator appears with seconds: ""07 February 2018 - 6:30:00". But I dont want to show the seconds. I want this format ""07 February 2018 - 6:30".

Do you know how to do this?

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


        var admins= {!!  $admin!!}

        $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
            let id = $(this).attr("id");
            let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
                name: "",
                date: "",
            };

            //alert(data.date); // 2018-02-07 6:30:00
            $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
            ...
            $("input[name='date']").val(data.date);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong along the line but from the Javascript end, [moment](https://momentjs.com/) can come to your rescue:

So, an example will be:

```
moment(data.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY h:mm')
```

> PS: You have to include moment from cdn or install it via npm

Comment: Thanks but with that code I get an issue. In the form there is a radio button "Create new administrator" when this button is selected the form fields should reset. The issue is that when using that moment code when the "Create new administrator" radio button is selected all fields reset unless the date field. Do you know why?

Comment: @jon truthfully, I don't understand why the field is not cleared. But perhaps you may want to clear out manually using jquery say: `$("input[name='date']").val('')` should clear it. This may point you to the root of the issue you are having.